# Error on git svn fetch: svn-remote "svn" unknown

Tags: git, svn

I am trying to migrate my svn repositories to git and I am facing a ridiculous error after I execute the following command:

```
git svn fetch
```

the error is :

```
[svn-remote "svn"] unknown
```

I already looked on the Internet for several suggestions but none worked.

Anyone had this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one-time conversion of SVN to git, svn2git should be used instead of git-svn. There are many tools with this name. Probably the best is the KDE one at https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. To analyze the SVN repo history upfront for building up proper rules for svn2git, you might use svneverever from here: http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763

Regarding your actual error, did you `git svn clone` before? Without it being done before you cannot do a `git svn fetch` which is just for bringing the newest changes in that were not fetched before.

Comment: Yes, I am aiming for one-time conversion from SVN to git. I have been following [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-synchronize) tutorial and that's where I got stuck with this error on fetch. And I did clone yes, I can see the folder and the content.

Comment: This tutorial is bullshit for a one-time conversion. `git svn` is really great if you company or whatever insists on using a Subversion server but you want to use Git as front-end client utility. But for one-time conversion it is not the right tool. Especially if your Subversion history gets a bit more complex or you want to combine different SVN repos in one SVN URL to one Git repository, or want to split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories and so on.

Comment: Besides that `svn2git` (the KDE one) is a bazillion faster than `git svn` and produces much better results, providing muuuch more flexibility to convert your history the right way.

Comment: Wow, okay, did not know. So I am going to use [svn2git](https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export), although it seems a bit more complicated than the tutorial I followed but nevertheless I'll try. The key here I guess is writing the rules. Will look into it, thanks.

Comment: Yes, the rules are the key. There are some examples included and if you have more complex requirements because complicated history or you want to split into multiple Git repos or combine different SVN repos into one Git repo, or other complex cases, just post a question here with tag `svn2git`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
[svn-remote "svn"] unknown
```

The error means that the git is not able to find your svn configuration named *svn* in your `.git\config`.

I had to change the line

```
[svn-remote "sometext"]
```

to

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
```